# Data labeling by df columns with using ternary operation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ternary

I have the code below that does not work as I want but the mean is clear I guess. In pandas normally we can labeling with `df["Label] = df["Column1"] > df["Column2"]` like this. However, when I try labeling with ternary as below, it does not work as I expected. Is there any way to do this with ease?

```
df["Label"] = "1" if df["Column1"] > df["Column2"] else "2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.